# How can I style the JPlayer poster element?

Tags: jquery, css, jplayer

I am using JPlayer and I would like to include the poster element to display the album cover associated with the song playing.

I can get the poster element to display but the problem is styling the image to suit my design. JPlayer seems to be adding inline styles into the code which I can override in my external stylesheet using !important but I am wondering if this is the best method to achieve this?

I have been researching this for hours and there does not seem to be much covering it which suggests to me it is something very simple I am overlooking.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make your styles **important** or **specific**

See css [important](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/) and [specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/07/css-specificity-and-inheritance/) documentation for details

Comment: Appreciate the reply Akshay I think I wanted to just check there wasn't something I was missing related to JPlayer itself, many thanks!

Comment: THIS DOES NOT WORK - Might try it before you post it :) - I am still researching this as well.

Answer (score 0):

jPlayer declares the inline class using !important for the inline styling. This results in your CSS not being used. The work around this is to over ride the img tag (at least that's how i got it to work - im sure there is another way)

```
.jp-jplayer img { 
margin-left: 105px !important;
}
```